# Merge multiple array in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, arraylist

Let us say I have a set of data of the first name

```
first name : `{ "abc","bvd","jhhg", "jju","jju"}`
Last name : `{ "hhh","uuu","tre", "vvg","yyy"}`
Age : `{ "44","33","34", "34,"65"}`
```

I want the result to return as

```
{
"fname" : "abc",
"lname" : "hhh",
"age" : "44"
},
{
"fname" : "bvd",
"lname" : "uuu",
"age" : "33"
},
{
"fname" : "jhhg",
"lname" : "tre",
"age" : "34"
}
```

How to do it in php / laravel

I have achieved the result but the response is too slow

```
  $cart = array();

   for($i = 1;$i<=($qty);$i++)
   {

       $fnames = CreateFirstName::all()->random(1);

       $fname = ($fnames[0]->fname);

       $images = CreateImageName::all()->random(1);

       $image = ($images[0]->imagelocation);


       $lnames = CreateLastName::all()->random(1);
       $lname = ($lnames[0]->lname);

       $cart[] = [
           'id' => $images[0]->id,
           'fname' => mb_substr($fname, 0, 10),
           'lname' => mb_substr($lname, 0, 10),
           'age' => rand(18,43),
           'city' => $region_name,
           'image' => $image

       ];

   }


   $collection = collect($cart);
```

[image]

The response is coming more than 20000 ms on the server or local enviroment

Comment: "_how to do it in php / laravel_" Research on the internet, start coding, ask for help if you run into any errors. Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, please add a little more detail: should only the first three datasets be returned? Or is `jju`  somehow not permitted to be included?

Comment: @kobid, do you need just 3 elements or all of them to returned in the way you have shared in expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the size of all the 3 arrays is same

```
$finalArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($firstArray);$i++){
    $finalArray[] = array("fname"=>$firstArray[$i], "lname"=>$lastArray[$i],"age"=>$ageArray[$i]);
}
```

`$finalArray` has what you have.

Comment: That will not return OP's desired result though, but _all_ elements from the arrays

Comment: The "_I want the result to return as_" part still only has three elements

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer you could also use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

`array_map` will essentially take one or more arrays and iterate over them by passing the current iteration of each array to the callback function:

```
$people = array_map(function ($fname, $lname, $age) {
    return [
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'age'   => $age,
    ];
}, $firstNames, $lastNames, $ages);
```

You could then make it even shorter by using [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

```
$people = array_map(function ($fname, $lname, $age) {
    return compact('fname', 'lname', 'age');
}, $firstNames, $lastNames, $ages);
```